# Graylog regex extract first valid Mac Address in message

Tags: regex, graylog3

I am trying to extract the first valid common mac address out of several different message entries in Graylog. I can do it with different Grok Extractors, but am wanting to do it with Regex so I can do conversions on the Mac to all lower case. Below are some sample messages and the Grok Patterns that work.

Question, how would I convert these Grok extractors to regex and or is there a single regex that would work in all 4 examples? Basically the regex would just need to match the first valid MAC address in each string and extract it.

Sample 1:
Equinox: *spamApTask1: Mar 20 15:26:04.033: #CAPWAP-3-ECHO_ERR: capwap_ac_sm.c:7019 Did not receive heartbeat reply; AP: 00:3a:9a:48:9b:40

Sample 2:
Equinox: *spamReceiveTask: Mar 17 12:34:39.264: #CAPWAP-3-DTLS_CONN_ERR: capwap_ac.c:934 00:3a:9a:30:f5:90: DTLS connection not found forAP 192.168.99.74 (43456), Controller: 192.168.99.2 (5246) send packet

Sample3:
Equinox: *spamApTask1: Mar 22 08:35:14.562: #LWAPP-4-SIG_INFO1: spam_lrad.c:44474 Signature information; AP 00:14:1b:61:f8:40, alarm ON, standard sig NULL probe resp 1, track per-Macprecedence 2, hits 1, slot 0, channel 1, most offending MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00 #yes but must make Mac lowercase

Sample 4:
Equinox: *idsTrackEventTask: Mar 22 08:40:13.816: #WPS-4-SIG_ALARM_OFF: sig_event.c:656 AP   00:14:1B:61:F8:40 : Alarm OFF, standard sig NULL probe resp 1, track=per-Mac preced=2 hits=1 slot=0 channel=1 yes but must make Mac lowercase

```
Sample1 Grok pattern:%{GREEDYDATA}AP: {COMMONMAC:WLC_APBaseMac}
Sample2 Grok pattern:%{GREEDYDATA}capwap_ac.c:934 %{COMMONMAC:WLC_APBaseMac}
Sample3 Grok pattern:%{GREEDYDATA}AP %{COMMONMAC:WLC_APBaseMac}
Sample4 Grok pattern:%{GREEDYDATA}AP %{COMMONMAC:WLC_APBaseMac}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a pattern, which matches 5 groups of 2 hex digits followed by a semicolon, followed by the last 6th group of 2 hex digits:

```
(?i)(?:[0-9a-f]{2}:){5}[0-9a-f]{2}
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/Uscs8A/1). The `(?i)` at the start make the search case-insensitive.

**UPDATED**

If the above regex does not work in Graylog then you can try the very basic form of it, where all the quantifiers and character sets are expanded:

```
[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]:[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/r87rdj/2).

Comment: This works perfectly on the demo site, however it fails in Graylog.  As I understand it, Graylog uses a form of Java Regex.  So there are some minor differences in syntax that I am struggling with.

Comment: To be more specific Graylog uses Java Pattern Regex?